# find the row of a matrix with the largest element in column i

Tags: python

Beginner python,

I want to create a method like: `max(mat,i)=` the row with the maximum value in the column i of matrix mat.

For example, I have a matrix `a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`, then the largest value of the `i=3` column is `9` and so `max(a,3)=[7,8,9]`.

I'm wondering if there is a builtin function in python?

Comment: isn't the row containing max is `[7,8,9]` not `[3,6,9]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built-in functions max()

```
def matrix_max(matrix,column):
    temp = []
    for i in matrix:
        for j,item in enumerate(i):
            if j == column-1:
                temp.append(item)
    return max(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is not a builtin function in python itself. I would recommend just building the utility yourself, since it's basically just a max over specified list out of matrix, which isn't hard to implement.